# MVC to WebApi calls losing session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using MVC and WebApi in same project, not using Session in WebApi.

In MVC BaseController I have something along these line

```
protected const string HOME = "HOME";

protected SessionDataStore SessionDataStore
{
    get
    {
        if ((Session[HOME] != null) && (Session[HOME] is SessionDataStore))
        {
            return (SessionDataStore)Session[HOME];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        Session[HOME] = value;
    }
}


public class SessionDataStore
    {
        public Request CurrentRequest { get; set; }
        public Customer CurrentCustomer { get; set; }
        public List<Salutation> Salutations { get; set; }
        public WebServiceConfiguration CurrentConfiguration { get; set; }
        public List<int> CurrentConfigurationIds { get; set; }
        public List<int> CurrentAttributeIds { get; set; }

public SessionDataStore()
        {
            CurrentRequest = new Request();
            CurrentCustomer = new Customer();
            Salutations = new List<Salutation>()
                              {
                                  new Salutation() { Id = 1, Name = "Mr", },
                                  new Salutation() { Id = 2, Name = "Mrs", },
                                  new Salutation() { Id = 3, Name = "Miss", },
                                  new Salutation() { Id = 4, Name = "Ms", },
                                  new Salutation() { Id = 5, Name = "Dr", },
                                  new Salutation() { Id = 6, Name = "Prof", },
                                  new Salutation() { Id = 7, Name = "Other", }
                              };
            CurrentConfiguration = new WebServiceConfiguration();
            CurrentConfigurationIds= new List<int>();
            CurrentAttributeIds = new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

In my MVC project, I call the web API and update the Session object like this.

I initialise SessionDataStore in the index page to a new object

```
var client = new HttpClient(_handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(string.Concat(GetBaseUrl().AbsoluteUri + "api/request/", requestId)).Result;  
SessionDataStore.CurrentRequest = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Request>().Result : null;
```

The status code is Success but then I am losing the session.
Not sure why this is happening. I am using inProc session

Comment: What do you mean by `not using Session in WebApi`. Can you show more code (where is the last snippet coming from)?

Comment: Last snippet comes from the MVC app which calls into the WebApi

Answer (score 3):

Web API is REST-compliant, and REST is *stateless*. In other words, no session. You cannot access the session in a Web API action. If you need to interact with the session via an AJAX call, you will need to simply create an MVC `Controller` action to handle it instead of a Web API `ApiController` action.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find the answer yet, this is how you can enable session usage inside web api request. You have to write the `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest` inside the `Global.asax.cs` like this:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    if(IsWebApiRequest())
        HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}

private bool IsWebApiRequest()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Contains("/api/");
}
```